# edquota failed to update quota: cannot change current block allocation

Tags: manjaro, quota

I tried to modify the quota using `edquota` on Manjaro but get this warning and the quota settings is not changed:

```
$ sudo edquota trusted
edquota: WARNING - /dev/sda7: cannot change current block allocation
```

The original quota of user `trusted` is:

```
$ sudo quota trusted
Disk quotas for user trusted (uid 1001): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/sda7      20*      1       3   6days       4       0       0
```

I changed `blocks` from 20 to 30 but got such a warning as above. Why is it happening? What is the correct way to the change quota of user?

---

#### Update

I think I figure it out. The `blocks` field shows how many blocks a user has used and should not be modified manually. One should modify `soft` and `hard` in `edquota`.